# emacs, projectile and symbolic link

Tags: emacs

I am using emacs and projectile for managing a C/C++ project. and now I am running into an issue related to symbolic links.

The root directory of my project is /export/work, and it only contains a few symbolic links, such as /export/work/CC1, and /export/work/CC2; and they point to the directories /export/CC1, and /export/CC2, respectively.  I only have read access to /export directory.

I created an empty /export/work/.projectile to denote /export/work is the root of the project. Now I am opening file /export/work/CC1/test.cpp in Emacs, and trying to switch to its correspondent head file test.h(it does exist), I get "you are not in a project".

I understand this message since /export/work/CC1/test.cpp is really /export/CC1/test.cpp, and we don't have a .projectile file if we trace back along path /export/CC1.

If looking at the file by using symbolic link, then we have path /export/work/CC1, and we can find .projectile along this path.

What should I do to make emacs detect my .projectile while I am editing test.cpp?

Thank you for the help.